# Zero vector and span relationship

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S:=\{u_1,u_2,...,u_k\}\subseteq \Bbb R^n$. I understand that $0∈\text{span}(S)$ because $0$ can always be a building block of $\Bbb R^n$, but can I say that $0$ is always an element in $S$? It is not wrong to say that $0$ is an element in $S$ since it does not affect any vector inside the set but can I make such an assumption in this case?

Comment: No. let $S= \{1\}$, then the span of $S$ is the reals but clearly zero is not in $S$.

Comment: This question was just heavily downvoted and closed: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3821339/linear-span-vector-is-0-always-a-subset-of-a-set-of-u-that-spans-bbb-r3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. For example you lose the property of linear indipendence (if $S$ has it ) : if you put the zero vector inside $S$, then the set of vectors becomes linearly dependent , which in many cases is the opposite of what you want (e.g. see basis of a vector space ).

Comment: Ok,so it is false, because there's always a linear combination when all the vectors  times zero (constant)? Amirite?

Comment: I mean the sum of all vectors times the constant zero

Comment: if you mean that you can then create the zero vector by summing all the other vectors (say linearly independent) times zero and the zero vector one by a $\alpha \neq 0$ then yes

Comment: K,thanks, I get it now

Comment: To double confirm again, any a(u1)+b(u2) (linear combination) is not contain in S, but contain in span{s} right? And how do I accept an answer? I'm new to Math stack

Comment: if you have linearly indipendent vectors and $a,b \neq 0$ then yes. For the second question see the link of my last comment

Comment: sorry not $a,b \neq 0$ but you have to be careful because for example $a \cdot u_1 + b \cdot u_2$ can be equal to $u_1$ or $u_2$ with the right choices on coefficients.